# Does Chinese have a phrase equivalent to "For all I know"?

Tags: mandarin, word-choice, equivalent-phrase, phrase

There is an expression in English:

> *"For all I know, ...."*

The following clause often has a modal expressing uncertainty or the hypothetical nature of the assertion, like "might", "may", "could", or "would".

> For all I know, he might have gone abroad.
>
> For all I know, she doesn't even work there anymore.
>
> For all I know, the test hasn't even been written yet.

The usage is usually something like this. You are talking about some topic. You disavow even a basic level of certainty about the topic by saying "For all I know, **X**", meaning something like "I can't even be sure that **X** isn't true. How can I say anything useful about the topic, if I can't even rule out possibility **X**?"

This is **not** the same as "To the best of my knowledge, **X**" (which means you really think **X**, you are just saying you are unsure). I think that "As far as I know" is more like "To the best of my knowledge" than "For all I know", but I think it might have some flexibility. I don't know.

=======================

So, my question is whether Chinese has any equivalent phrases or ways to express "For all I know"? I've seen a few instances of `据我所知`, but I don't know whether that's idiomatic Chinese or just a stilted and academic translation. Also, I don't know whether it really has any of the same implications that "For all I know" has. For all I know, `据我所知` is just a neutral statement like "To the best of my knowledge"!

Comment: If uncertainty is expressed in "For all I know", then can the first example do without "might"? Is there any uncertainty in this statement "For all I know, he has already left the country"?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow The way I phrased it and the way you phrased it are both acceptable.

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that there is no implicit uncertainty in the phrase at all. "For all I know" is the same as "for all that I know", "to the best of my knowledge" or "as far as I know". Depending on the tone, it may sound rude and can be spoken by someone who is irritated and wants to end the questioning from the asker.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Part of what I was explaining is that "For all I know" is not the same as "to the best of my knowledge". If I believed he had left the country but wasn't sure, I could say "As far as I know, he has already left the country." If you're asking me if he's leaving next week or the week after, and I'm trying to tell you I don't have any clue, I might say "As far as I know, he's already left the country", implying I don't even know whether he's still here, much less when he's leaving.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. You are right. "For all I know" actually means the person not knowing much at all. @fefe's answer is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can only give some possible translations based on your explanation of "For all I know":

> For all I know, he might have gone abroad.
>
> 他说不准出国了呢。
>
> For all I know, she doesn't even work there anymore.
>
> 她没准已经不在哪工作了呢。
>
> For all I know, the test hasn't even been written yet.
>
> 测试题说不准还没出呢。

We would use "说不准" "没准" and things like that to express the uncertainty. I can't think of one phrase that would have the same meaning of "For all I know" as your explained.

Comment: I think `For all I know` should be `以我所知` because `以` similar to `from`/`for`, `我` = `I`, and `所知` = `things (one) knows`.

Comment: @PeteC. no, that is an incorrect definition of the English idiom. For more details see: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92207/what-is-the-correct-definition-and-usage-of-for-all-i-know

Comment: These are good answers. It's true, `以我所知` is not the same, even though it seems like it is, it doesn't have the same feel.

Answer (score 5):

据我所知…… is good, but reminds me of newspaper writing.

就我所知…… is also quite reasonable (and probably the best choice in my opinion).

我所知道的是…… is yet another 所 + verb phrase that could work.

我还以为…… could also work in certain contexts, remembering that we aren't going word-for-word.

Comment: Can you comment on whether you think the examples you gave have the same connotations of "For all I know", or if they're just equivalent to "To the best of my knowledge"?

Comment: If you truly wish to "disavow even a basic level of certainty about the topic" then I'm not sure how "For all I know..." differs from "I [simply] don't know." The other respondent's suggestion of 说不准 is good; in a similar vein, another relevant term is 说不定.

Comment: I guess maybe a more direct rendering of the semantics of "For all I know, __X__" would be something along the lines of "连 __X__ 我也不知道"

Comment: Perhaps, though "I don't even know..." is pretty similar to "I [simply] don't know." If I wanted to convey the meaning of a sentence like "For all I know, she doesn't even work there anymore," I'd probably just say "I don't know where she works now" (我不知道她现在在哪里工作) or "Is she still working at the same place?" (她还在以前的公司工作吗？)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because these phrases do not convey the nuance in the English idiom properly IMO

Answer (score 2):

据我所知 is neutral, and hence is not appropriate in this case.
I agree with fefe that "说不准" can be used, but where I'm from, we generally use "说不定" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Franky, for the example sentences you wrote, I think 有可能 is a good way to translate "For all I know". This Chinese wording can imply that you don't know. It's just more common than any more direct translation of "For all I know".